# Choosing which system (windows/ubuntu) to boot doesn't work when mouse connected by usb

Tags: dual-boot, usb, mouse, bios, hp-pavilion

Recently, I installed ubuntu 22.04 on my hp pavilon, and everything works normally for the most part, except during booting. If I turn on the laptop when a mouse (I have tried this with two different mice) is connected by an usb port. Then the normal booting screen shows up, but I can't do anything. None of my keys on they keyboard work, neither does the mouse. Also, usually if I would wait 10 seconds, whichever option was selected would boot up, but that doesn't happen either.

Comment: have you tried using grub boot-repair

Comment: sudo apt install boot-repair

Comment: mouse does not work on grub. you can only use a keyboard.